# Learn to predict future customer's behavior from history

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I have a dataset which contains visiting history from customers.

It has three columns in dataset including customer ID, AM/PM (visit at AM or PM) and Weekday/Weekend (visit on weekday or weekend).

I want to learn from this dataset and select the top 50 customers who have the biggest chance to visit in specified input (like AM / Weekday).

For now, I create model for each customer by using one-class SVM (I only have positive (visit) data). Since the one-class SVM only has binary output, I can only tell the certain customer will visit or not in specified input, rather than selecting the top 50 customers.

I was wondering if there is an algorithm that can learn from a positive-only dataset and give a score or probability like output?

Comment: This a question adequate to Data Science Stack Exchange (http://datascience.stackexchange.com/). You might get more specialized opinion there. Also you might want to take a look at this: https://pkghosh.wordpress.com/2015/07/06/customer-conversion-prediction-with-markov-chain-classifier/

Answer (score 0):

That's a subcategory problem within machine learning. You can learn a lot reading this survey: "One-Class Classification: Taxonomy of Study and Review of
Techniques" (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.0049.pdf). Hope it helps.